# use result of a function applied to groupby for calculation on the original df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I am having some data which look like as shown below `df`. 
I am trying to calculate first the mean angle for each group using the function `mean_angle`. The calculated mean angle is then used to do another calculation per group using the function `fun`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

**generate sample data**

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4]).repeat(4)
x1 = 90 + np.random.randint(-15, 15, size=a.size//2 - 2 )
x2 = 270 + np.random.randint(-50, 50, size=a.size//2 + 2 )

b = np.concatenate((x1, x2))
np.random.shuffle(b) 

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b})
```

The returned dataframe is printed below.

```
    a   b
0   1   295
1   1   78
2   1   280
3   1   94
4   2   308
5   2   227
6   2   96
7   2   299
8   3   248
9   3   288
10  3   81
11  3   78
12  4   103
13  4   265
14  4   309
15  4   229
```

**My functions are `mean_angle` and `fun`**

```
def mean_angle(deg):

    deg = np.deg2rad(deg)

    deg = deg[~np.isnan(deg)]

    S = np.sum(np.sin(deg))
    C = np.sum(np.cos(deg))
    mu = np.arctan2(S,C)
    mu = np.rad2deg(mu)

    if mu <0:
        mu = 360 + mu

    return mu

def fun(x, mu):

    return  np.where(abs(mu - x) < 45, x, np.where(x+180<360, x+180, x-180))
```

*what I have tried*

```
mu = df.groupby(['a'])['b'].apply(mean_angle)

df2 = df.groupby(['a'])['b'].apply(fun, args = (mu,)) #this function should be element wise
```

I know it is totally wrong but I could not come up with a better way.

***The desired output is something like this*** where `mu` the mean_angle per group

```
 a   b   c
0   1   295 np.where(abs(mu - 295) < 45, 295, np.where(295 +180<360, 295 +180, 295 -180))
1   1   78 np.where(abs(mu - 78) < 45, 78, np.where(78 +180<360, 78 +180, 78 -180))
2   1   280 np.where(abs(mu - 280  < 45, 280, np.where(280  +180<360, 280  +180, 280  -180))
3   1   94                ...
4   2   308               ...
5   2   227                .
6   2   96                 .
7   2   299                .
8   3   248                .
9   3   288                .
10  3   81                 .
11  3   78                 .
12  4   103                .
13  4   265                .
14  4   309                .
15  4   229                .
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: @Ben.T I am okay changing the function `fun`

Comment: @rahlf23 I could find a way to do it! `groupby.apply` basically applies the function per group of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need your second function, just pass the necessary columns to `np.where()`. So creating your dataframe in the same manner and not modifying your `mean_angle` function, we have the following sample dataframe:

```
    a    b
0   1  228
1   1  291
2   1   84
3   1  226
4   2  266
5   2  311
6   2   82
7   2  274
8   3   79
9   3  250
10  3  222
11  3   88
12  4   80
13  4  291
14  4  100
15  4  293
```

Then create your `c` column (containing your `mu` values) using `groupby()` and `transform()`, and finally apply your `np.where()` logic:

```
df['c'] = df.groupby(['a'])['b'].transform(mean_angle)
df['c'] = np.where(abs(df['c'] - df['b']) < 45, df['b'], np.where(df['b']+180<360, df['b']+180, df['b']-180))
```

Yields:

```
    a    b    c
0   1  228  228
1   1  291  111
2   1   84  264
3   1  226  226
4   2  266  266
5   2  311  311
6   2   82  262
7   2  274  274
8   3   79  259
9   3  250   70
10  3  222   42
11  3   88  268
12  4   80  260
13  4  291  111
14  4  100  280
15  4  293  113
```